# How to call a function after switching a player, it works but only on 2 calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting up a 2 player game with players switching turns after they have finished their move. I have got the players switching after 2 turns but it doesn't work after that.

```
function nextPlayer() {
    if (
        activeLocation().currCell === player1Location().currCell &&
        player1Location().currCell !== player2Location().currCell
    ) {
        deactivatePlayerOne();
        activatePlayerTwo();
        activeLocation().currCell = player2Location().currCell;


        moveDown();
        moveRight();
        moveUp();
        moveLeft();
        dragInit();
    } 
}
```

Players should be able to switch multiple times until the game is finish.

Comment: here is my js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vallis/7sv0ky5f/7/#&togetherjs=0ktKcMlR34

Comment: I suggest before checking currCell you compare activeLocation with player1 or player2 location.

Comment: @SPlatten i am doing this in this line i think 

activeLocation().currCell === player1Location().currCell

Comment: Another thing is it works the first 2 times after that is breaks